# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied - Python cannot write/open/read any text or image files

Tags: python, windows, file-permissions

This stuff was ok until recently and I've searched everywhere.
I'm trying to get an image from the internet and then download it.
I'm using python on Windows installed via Anaconda. THe same error occurs on powershell as well as anaconda prompt.

**My code (test.py):**

```
from PIL import Image
import requests
from io import BytesIO
import cv2
import numpy

img_url = 'https://d.newsweek.com/en/full/520858/supermoon-moon-smartphone-photo-picture.jpg'
response = requests.get(img_url)
img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))


uid = 1
fname = 'test'
x_start, y_start, x_end, y_end = 0,0,10,10
crp = img.crop((x_start, y_start, x_end, y_end)) 
crp.save('test.jpg')
```

**The error** (when running `python test.py` in console):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\imgtest.py", line 16, in <module>
    crp.save('test.jpg')
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2148, in save
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "w+b")
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'test.jpg'
```

**Things I've tried**

1. Changing permissions of the folder that the file is in
2. Running command prompt as administrator
3. Tested creating a text file as well using `f = open("demo.txt", "w")`. The error this time is:

   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File ".\imgtest.py", line 15, in 
   f = open("demo.txt", "w")
   PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'demo.txt'

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html?highlight=save#PIL.Image.Image.save), try to pass the format as a param:

```
crp.save('test', "jpg")
```

or

```
crp.save('test', "JPEG")
```

Also from the documentation, Your IOError Raise when:
the file could not be written. The file may have been created and may contain partial data.

Comment: No luck sadly, the error has changed to "Error in saving file" now though.
Also I've made sure that the folder is empty as well - It seems like it cannot be created in the first place..